# Is there a way to only add a property if it is defined via the spread operator?

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `name` and I want to add it to an object only if it's defined and not `null`. For example, I check the value of `name`:

```js
let name = null;
if(nameExists) {
    name = 'John Smith';
}
```

Then I only want to add it to the object as a field if it exists and is not null.

```js
const results = {
   title: $(el).find('.title').text(), 
   name
};
```

But this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Try it this way:  `const results = {title: $(el).find('.title').text(), name: name ?? "John Smith"};`

Comment: Just conditionally assign it. No need for spread

Comment: you should add the property to the object conditionally... since you don't want it to appear at all if a given variable is undefined or null. `if (condition) { results[varname] = value; }`

Answer (score 1):

Well, to do that, you have to spread an object containing the property or an empty object, depending on whether you want to add the property:

```
const results = {
   title: $(el).find('.title').text(), 
   ...(
     name !== null
       ? {name}
       : {}
   )
};
```

But I think a conditional assignment could be clearer:

```
const results = {
   title: $(el).find('.title').text()
};

if(name !== null)
  results.name = name
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example clears your concept.

```
function addName(name) {
    let obj = {"site":"stackoverflow"}; // create an object)=(it may be pre-existing)
    if(name) {
        obj = {...obj, name}; // add name field to obj only if it exists
    }
    return obj;
}

const ex1 = addName();
const ex2 = addName('John Smith');
console.log('If name is null: ', ex1);
console.log('If name exists: ', ex2);
```

Comment: `if (name) { obj.name = name; }`

Comment: @SergeyP.akaazure but in the question he mentioned to solve it via spread operator.